# Is there an option to make shiny app displayed as full-sized window on start?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

When running a Shiny app, it opens in a separate window. I want it to open full-sized to fit my whole screen without opening in a browser. Is there a way to do this?

I don't have a lot of knowledge about JavaScript and CSS, so my attempts to use them to resize the window haven't been successful.